# Change image format that taken by camera and change image size and send to SQL server

Tags: android

I take a photo by camera in android studio and show it in my layout. I want to change format of taken image to PNG and resize it and send this image to SQL server in android studio.

this is my codes:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_codesender);
        
        capimage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capimage);
        capimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        camera = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camera);
        clear=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        filename=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.filename);
        uploadimage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.uploadimage);
        imgView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        capimage =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capimage);
        imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        clear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        uploadimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        capimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //capture picture from camera
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // capture picture
                Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // Create a File reference for future access
                photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);

                Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Codesender.this, "com.codepath.fileprovider.ATZ_Group", photoFile);
                camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider);

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(camIntent, CameraRequest);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Codesender.this, "camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

}
        

    //capture image
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CameraRequest) {
            imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            capimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            uploadimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            resultPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imgView.setImageBitmap(resultPhoto);
            capimage.setImageBitmap(resultPhoto);
            filename.setText(" service Image " + number);
            clear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgView.setImageResource(0);
                clear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                uploadimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                capimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                filename.setText("no image attached");
            }
        });


    }

    // Returns the File for a photo stored on disk given the fileName
    public File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
        // Get safe storage directory for photos
        // Use `getExternalFilesDir` on Context to access package-specific directories.
        // This way, we don't need to request external read/write runtime permissions.
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_TAG);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "failed to create directory");
        }

        // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);

        return file;
    }
```

and this is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Farsi_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/My_Company"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/Highlight_color"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Farsi_name"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ATZ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TACOM "
            android:textColor="#CF0202"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/Highlight_color"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Service"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/Highlight_color"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Warning_Note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/Warning_Note"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sc1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Warning_Note"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:popupBackground="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Return_Code"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="شماره پذیرش را وارد نمایید"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="#F40C0C"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Return_Code"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="مبلغ دریافتی کل (تومان)"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/afzudebtn"
            android:layout_width="48sp"
            android:layout_height="48sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"
             />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
            android:hint="مالیات ارزش افزوده"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="مالیات ارزش افزوده"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/jamekol"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout11"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
                android:hint="جمع کل"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                tools:ignore="InefficientWeight" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnertype"
        style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/jamekol"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnertype"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:background="@drawable/border4"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border4"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/uploadimage"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload"
            android:background="@drawable/border4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/filename"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="هیچ عکسی ضمیمه نشده است"
            android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/capimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/border4"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Return_Note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border2"
        android:ems="20"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="توضیحات را وارد نمایید"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Sendcode2"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/Return_Note"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonborder"
                android:fontFamily="@font/iransansdn"
                android:text="ارسال آنلاین"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is image of my layout:

[image]

please help me to change format of picture image to PNG and resize image. then I want to send this image to SQL server.

Comment: So you want to change a jpg file in a png file and meanwhile change resolution. Why posting all this camera code to produce a jpg file? You could have started with a jpg file already on the device.

Comment: @blackapps i want to change format of my image to change the size of image and send it to sql server

Comment: You are only repeating yourself. That brings nothing. And you did not remove that tag.

Comment: @blackapps if you have any code with the jpg format please guide me to change size and coding image and send to sql server. thanks

Comment: Those are three things. You should only come with one problem.

Comment: @blackapps plese exlain more